# Storing a child-class pointer in a map of parent-class pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

So say I have a parent class called `Libitem` and a child class called `Book`. If I store a pointer of `Book` inside a map of pointer of `Libitem`, would I get a pointer of `Book` back when I try to access it again? Like this:

```
std::map<int, Libitem*> catalog;
Libitem* b = new Book();
catalog[1] = b;
Libitem* old_book = catalog[1]; //would old_book be a Book or a Libitem? In other word would it 
                               //have all the function of a Book class?
```

Comment: Please search for and read about *downcasting*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're retrieving your object like this:

```
Libitem* old_book = catalog[1];
```

With that, the compiler only knows that your have a variable named `old_book` of type *pointer to `Libitem`*. And if yourself you read that particular line alone, you'll notice that the only this is the only information you, and the compiler, have at that moment. That moment when you read this line yourself is the compile time. What you can know by reading the code.

When the program actually runs, that variable may point to an object of type `Book`. But this is only known when the program runs, hence, *runtime*.

Name lookup happens at compile-time in C++. When you call a function on an object like this:

```
// Type of an_object is a_struct
a_struct an_object;

an_object.member_function();
```

The compiler will look at what functions are available inside `a_struct`. Since the compiler is looking for that name in the struct the variable had been declared, names are really resolved at compile-time.

---

Let's go back to your case. You have a pointer to `Libitem`. If you try to access something inside it using the arrow:

```
old_book->something
```

To resolve what `something` is, the compiler will look inside `Libitem` for it, because the type of `old_book` is a pointer to `Libitem`.  Even if the pointer points to an instance of a child class, the only thing the compiler knows *for sure* is that the actual type of the object pointed to is at least `Libitem`.

Now, you the human knows more than the compiler. You know that the pointer `old_book` points to an instance of the class `Book`. You want to access members of `Book`.

For that, you must explicitly tell to the compiler that you want to use members that come from a subclass. For that to happen, your variable must be of the type `Book`, so the compiler will look in the appropriated class. To do this, you can cast your variable to another type. Since you cast the variable to a class that is lower in the hierarchy, it is called a *downcast*. The kind of cast we can use in this case is a `dynamic_cast`, a cast that will look at runtime what is the actual type of the instance pointed by the pointer:

```
if (Book* the_old_book = dynamic_cast<Book*>(old_book)) {
    // We can use the_old_book here, which his type is Book!
} else {
    // The cast failed, the real for of the variable is not Book,
    // and the_old_book points to nullptr
}
```

As you can see, we create a new pointer named `the_old_book`, which is initialized by the result of the cast. If the real type of the instance pointed by `old_book` is really not a `Book`, the cast will fail and return `nullptr`. Since this happens at runtime, we must validate our new variable using a runtime branch, a `if`. If the cast fail, the executed block will be the `else` block.

Comment: Alright thre whole casting mechanic is going to be pretty helpful... but just to make sure, the pointer stored in `catalog[1]` is always going to be techinically a child right? In other word, if I pass the pointer stored in `catalog[1]` to another vector or map, would I be able to retrieve it from the new collection and still be able to dynamic cast it to a `Book`?

Comment: Yes. The type of the actual instance is not going to change. You can create, copy and transform the pointer. If, in the end, the pointer points at the same location you allocated your object, you will be able to downcast it.

Answer (score 2):

It would be like any other polymorphic pointer: the functionality of a `Libitem`, but with any virtual overrides of a `Book` in the methods.

But: you will not have access to non-virtual methods of `Book`, whether it be a function/method having a completely different name to any method in `Libitem`, the same name but different parameter signature to a method in `Libitem`, or *non-virtual* cases of having the same name and signature as a method in `Libitem`.

Of course, if you're a strong-arm kind of person, you can downcast (as pointed out by @SomeProgrammerDude).

Comment: Wait so only virtual overrides of a Book can be accessed? Everything that is not virtual but is part of `Book`(and not inherited from `Libitem`) would not be accessible?

Comment: Anything not inherited from `Libitem` is non-accessible